# need help prioritizing output with a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to pull columns with a query where 'grad_year' is one of four years (4 OR statements), but I want entries of a specified year to appear first. This is the SQL I have.  In this example, I want entries from 2011, 2012, 2013, and 2014.  How do I get the 2012 entries, for example, to show up first?  The rest of the order wouldn't matter. Thank you!

```
SELECT       user_meta.grad_year,
             school_data.school
FROM         user_meta
  LEFT JOIN  school_data
  ON         user_meta.school_id = school_data.id
WHERE        school_id = 2
  AND        user_id != 102
  AND       (user_meta.grad_year = 2011
    OR       user_meta.grad_year = 2012
    OR       user_meta.grad_year = 2013
    OR       user_meta.grad_year = 2014)
LIMIT        0, 15
```

Comment: Off-topic, but I would use `AND user_meta.grad_year IN (2011,2012,2013,2014)` or a BETWEEN rather than 4 ORs.

Comment: @Brad, that makes little difference, still 4 tests, a `between` would cut that down to 2.

Comment: @Johan: Yea, I caught that but was trying to get to docs and keep forgetting about the ENTER submit. thank you though. ;-) EDIT: I also didn't know if the years were actually going to be in order all the time or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might help

```
ORDER BY 
 CASE 
  WHEN user_meta.grad_year = 2012 THEN 1 
  WHEN user_meta.grad_year = 2011 THEN 2 
  WHEN user_meta.grad_year = 2013 THEN 3 
  ELSE NULL 
 end
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the query to:

```
SELECT       user_meta.grad_year,
             school_data.school
FROM         user_meta
  LEFT JOIN  school_data
  ON         user_meta.school_id = school_data.id
WHERE        school_id = 2
  AND        user_id!=102
  AND       (user_meta.grad_year BETWEEN 2011 and 2014)
ORDER BY    (user_meta.grad_year = 2012) DESC
LIMIT        0, 15
```

This will show the `2012` items first and then all other items in accidental order.